# Undefined symbols for architecture arm64 Xcode 7 beta 2, Parse 1.7.5, Facebook 4.4.0

Tags: ios, parse-platform, facebook-ios-sdk

I'm currently using Xcode 7 beta 2, Parse 1.7.5 and Facebook 4.40. When I add this line of code in my AppDelegate.swift:

```
PFFacebookUtils.initializeFacebookWithApplicationLaunchOptions(launchOptions)
```

I get this error:

[image]

I just can't figure out how to fix the issue.

Comment: Are you using ParseFacebookUtils, or ParseFacebookUtilsV4?

Comment: @MingLi ParseFacebookUtilsV4